# powershell run script in parallel

Tags: multithreading, powershell, parallel-processing, start-job

i'm using windows server 2003, now i have a script to restart one specific service, can someone guide me how to run this script in parallel? i already use start-job, but seems it only run in backround but still sequential, below is my script:

file name: restart-service.ps1

```
$start = Get-Date
$Serverlist = Get-Content -path C:\Computers.txt

ForEach ($Server in $Serverlist){
start-job -scriptblock {param($Server) Restart-Service -InputObject $(Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Name "aspnet_state")} -ArgumentList $Server
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job
Get-Job | Receive-Job
$end = Get-Date
$timespan = $end - $start
$seconds = $timespan.TotalSeconds
Write-Host "This took me $seconds seconds."
```

or this

```
$start = Get-Date
$Server = Get-Content -path C:\Computers.txt

$scriptblock = {
    Param($Server)
    Restart-Service -InputObject $(Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Name "aspnet_state")
}
$Server | % {Start-Job -Scriptblock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $_ | Out-Null}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job

$end = Get-Date
$timespan = $end - $start
$seconds = $timespan.TotalSeconds
Write-Host "This took me $seconds seconds."
```

but i only can see the result, but can not see any result related information of my server's IP, can someone help me how to improve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Direction, tweak it for your specific needs... add timer etc...

```
$Serverlist = Get-Content -path C:\Computers.txt

Foreach ($Server in $Serverlist)
{
    Start-Job -Name "$Server-Job" -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Service -ComputerName $args[0] -Name "aspnet_state" | Restart-Service 
    } -ArgumentList $Server
}
```

It will Create a job with the ServerName for each server, to Get the Job status/info, use:

```
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```